# Why can I use request.path in rails4 and rails5, where is it documented?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, rack

I am wondering why I can use `request.path` in rails 4 or rails 5 even though it is not documented in ActionDispatch::Request.

```
logger.info(request)
# returns #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x007f7bf44e22e0>

logger.info(request.path)
# returns /home
```

No path method here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html

Is this method inherited from Rack?
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Request/Helpers#path-instance_method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails ActionDispatch::Request includes Rack::Request::Helpers (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3f2b7d60a52ffb2ad2d4fcf889c06b631db1946b/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb#L17).
So yes, you are right. This method is from Rack.